# How to get rid of insecure functions (sprintf, ...)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I want to get rid of all uses of insecure functions like `sprintf` and the like in a large C++ project.
I would like to have `errors or at least warnings`, that show me all occurrences for further reviewing.
I know, that on OpenBSD there is such a warning, but I'm on Linux. If I try to define a macro for `sprintf` I get errors in the `<cstdio>` header. So any good ideas, besides patching the system headers?

**Edit:**
Additional challenge is, that there is a sprintf function in a homegrown C++ string class. So, just grepping for sprintf results in a lot of false positives.

Comment: Those functions are only insecure if used incorrectly, like most functions. For example, replacing `strcpy` with `strncpy` is more likely to introduce problems than fix them.

Comment: `strcmp()` is insecure? Nope, cannot concurr. (Just as Matt says for the rest too)

Comment: Why don't you just `grep` for them?  Insisting on a compiler warning/error seems needlessly clumsy and indirect, and is more useful for preventing usage creeping back in.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, a secure function would shield you from a wrong usage as much as it can. That's the point. Saying "guns are safe, because you have to point them at someone to hurt him" is about as broken as saying sprintf is safe.

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to use `sprintf` in a secure way; replacing it with `snprintf` would be a significant improvement.  (Although any vararg function is implicitly insecure, and should be avoided.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Know your tools and use the proper one. That includes knowing how to size buffers (including knowing when you cannot do so properly with that tool).

Comment: @matt-mcnabb: I removed strcmp from the title, since it's indeed less insecure than sprintf.

Comment: @tony-d: Just grepping does not work, since I have another sprintf member function in a class.

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to use snprintf instead of sprintf?

Comment: @ansiwen: It should not have appreciably more overhead, so the change is just about free. Still, why not go one higher to [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) and the like?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure. The point is to find all occurrences of sprintf to be able to review them. So the title could also be _Finding all occurrences of potentially insecure functions_, but that's less catchy. ;-)

Comment: Is the `sprintf` member function `static`?  If not, then you still use `grep` by eliminating `sprintf` matches that are preceded by a `.` or `->`.  If so, then any use outside the class will necessary be prefixed with the class name and `::`, so again you can eliminate them.  Probably the easiest way to eliminate them is to pipe the grep results into a `| egrep -v '(<class>::|\.|->)sprintf'`.

Comment: @ansiwen C89 did not have snprintf. But it could be argued that you should download a freeware implementation of vsnprintf and use that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `Replacing strcpy with strncpy is more likely to introduce problems than fix them` Oh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers of @Deduplicator and @alastair I came up with the following solution, which works for me:

In a header file, that is included by every compile unit with the `-include` option of gcc (that was already there before), I added these lines:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#undef sprintf
extern "C" {
int sprintf(char *, const char*, ...) __attribute__((error("!!!DON'T USE sprintf(), USE snprintf() INSTEAD!!!")));
}
```

Of course you can replace `error` with `warning`. (For some reason `deprecated` did not produce a warning in my setup, didn't further research, why.)

Thanks to all contributers!

Comment: FWIW, on *some* platforms (particularly older ones, if you care about those) that won't link because the C library's `sprintf()` will clash with yours.  You need a `#define` as well as the `#undef` in that case to rename all the `sprintf`s.

Comment: @alastair: Good hint. Although, as long as I bail out with an error, I don't mind linking. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Even though I completely concurr with [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447418/how-to-get-rid-of-insecure-functions-sprintf-strcmp/24447615#comment37830007_24447418) that the functions are not bad, and you are quite indiscriminate in your banning, here ways to do so.

1. *Today is patch your headers day:*

   1. Copy your headers, then run grep to find those functions you fear.
   2. Add `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` to them.
   3. Recompile your project.
   4. Profit???
2. *Not patching headers?*

   Still, it might be better to go the direct way: Just grep your own project files.
   You can even save that search as a script for re-application.
3. Use the preprocessor (beware, we are changing reserved identifiers, which is bad!):

   Add a file "explosive_security.h" like this:

   ```
   inline static int my_deprecated() __attribute__ ((deprecated)) {return 0;}
   #undef strcmp
   #define strcmp (my_deprecated(), strcmp)
   ```

   And include it *after all other includes*.
   That should generate a warning and no error in most contexts, though always an error in some.

Comment: Ad 1.) Although I asked for solutions _besides patching the system headers_, the idea with `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` is quite nice.
Ad 2.) Any idea how to only grep for ::sprintf in the global namespace?
Ad 3.) How can I include a header after all other includes in a 500k lines project?

Comment: You won't get around inserting that line manually in all your source files. Unless you can accept other arbitrary includes breaking due to your change, in which case you might be able to take advantage of system header-file-guards to add your override header with a compiler option. Or creating a man-in-the-middle header, which includes the system header and then massages its data.

Comment: Another way to find all uses of a function is to grep for its name over your project. This presumes you don't do horrible things like build up a standard function name via token pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `#define`, not a more complex one.  For instance

```
#undef sprintf
#define sprintf __DO_NOT_CALL_SPRINTF
```

is much more likely to work without problems than

```
#undef sprintf
#define sprintf(s,f,...) __DO_NOT_CALL_SPRINTF(s, f, __VA_ARGS__)
```

If you still have difficulty, make sure you `#include` all relevant headers *before* you use the `#define`; an easy way to do this is to make a project-wide header file (call it "safety.h") and inside that header, do e.g.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#undef sprintf
#define sprintf __DO_NOT_CALL_SPRINTF
```

Of course, all of this may well be more trouble than it's really worth.

Comment: This is bad advice twice: using macros and using reserved identifiers.

Comment: @stefan If I saw code like this out of context, I might agree with you.  In this instance, however, the OP *wants* build failures when someone tries to use these functions (and yes, they're reserved identifiers — so?).  This approach has the merit of (a) being simple, and (b) not requiring edits to system headers (a far more heinous crime than using macros).

Comment: Do I really have to explain this? it's bad because it's UB to use reserved identifiers. It's the "wrongest" approach of all.

Comment: @stefan You need to make more of a distinction between the theoretical objection (that use of reserved identifiers is undefined behaviour) and the practical reality — which is that this will work on all C/C++ compilers I have ever seen (and there have been quite a few).  Further, the goal here is to eliminate all references to `sprintf` et al, so *there will be NO uses of these identifiers*.

Comment: I certainly don't need to make that distinction.  It's not standard conforming so any compiler including future versions may behave arbitrarily. There is no worse scenario, especially if you forget about such a bad construct.

Comment: @stefan No compiler is going to behave *arbitrarily* in the face of this kind of thing.  You need to reflect on *why* e.g. symbols starting "str" are reserved.  The reason is that otherwise there would be a risk of a clash between functions added to the C library by ANSI and user code.  In this particular instance, there's no reason to suppose that will be a problem — though the #undef is *absolutely* necessary because the standard library is free to use macros in its definition of e.g. `sprintf()`.

Comment: @alastair: although the macro doesn't work for me (conflict with member function of another C++ class), I would vote your answer up for the general idea to include the `<cstdio>` header before. Unfortunately my reputation is too low yet. ;-)